# call a setter from __init__ in Python

Tags: python, properties

How can I call a Python (v2.7) setter property from inside `__init__`? I written the following class but I dont know how to change it to make it work. I get an `AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute '_x'` exception. There are a few similar questions around here but couldnt find an answer so far. The idea is when the initialiser is called to do some processing/slicing and assign the result to an attribute

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self._x = self.x(a,b)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, a, b):
        self._x = "Get this from {} and make a dataframe like {}".format(a,b)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`self.x` is a *property*, so you'd just assign directly to it like you would with a regular attribute:

```
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.x = (a, b)
```

However, the setter is given **one** object, always; in the above case, it is passed a tuple; you could unpack it:

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    a, b = value
    self._x = "Get this from {} and make a dataframe like {}".format(a,b)
```

Note the `value` argument; that's the result of the assignment being passed to the setter.

Demo:

```
>>> class test(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.x = (a, b)
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return self._x
...     @x.setter
...     def x(self, value):
...         a, b = value
...         self._x = "Get this from {} and make a dataframe like {}".format(a,b)
...
>>> t = test(42, 'foo')
>>> t.x
'Get this from 42 and make a dataframe like foo'
```

Comment: Ah I see!! Excellent, works fine now, many thanks. My IDE, Pycharm, complains that `instance attribute _x is defined outside __init__`, I have assigned it to `None` in the initialiser, before calling the setter with `self._x = None`. I guess thats ok, right?

Comment: @Aenaon It might look prettier if you change your `__init__` function to use the line `self._x = self.x = (a, b)` rather than instantiating it to `None`.

Comment: There is no need to initialise it to None at all; it'll be set by the property in `__init__`.

Comment: Right, but PyCharm is complaining about `self._x` being an instance variable that's set in `@x.setter` rather than `__init__` (which I agree with in spirit, even if it's misguided in the case or properties). So, he had the line `self._x = None` before `self.x = (a, b)` to avoid the linter warning.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: Surely there are better ways to silence that warning.